# Spark Sql Dedup Rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a common use case of deduping a table in rows' creation order.

For example, we have an event log of user actions. A user marks his favorite category from time to time.
In our analytics phase we would like to know only the user's last favorite category.

Example data:

```
id  action_type value date 
123 fav_category 1    2016-02-01
123 fav_category 4    2016-02-02
123 fav_category 8    2016-02-03
123 fav_category 2    2016-02-04
```

We would like to get only the most recent update according to the date column. We could of-course do it in sql:

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over (
      partition by id,action_type order by date desc) as rnum from tbl
  ) 
where rnum=1;
```

But then, it is not partially aggregated on the mappers side and we'll get all the data shuffled to the reducers.

I have posted a Jira with this issue [SPARK-17662](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17662) and it was closed with a better SQL style suggestion:

```
select id,
       action_type,
       max(struct(date, *)) last_record
from   tbl
group by id,action_type
```

While this solution is much cleaner is still has two problems:

1. This trick doesn't work if one of the fields is not sortable (like map<>)
2. If later in the flow we select only some of the fields, we will not get the push-down predicate to optimize our flow and disregard un-needed fields from the begining.

We have eventually written a UDAF for this that overcomes problem #1 but still suffer from problem #2.

Does anyone have any idea for a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that wants our current solution. Here is the code for the UDAF - notice that we had to use some internal function so we are in package org.apache.spark.sql.types:

```scala
package org.apache.spark.sql.types

case class MaxValueByKey(child1: Expression, child2: Expression) extends DeclarativeAggregate {

  override def children: Seq[Expression] = child1 :: child2 :: Nil

  override def nullable: Boolean = true

  // Return data type.
  override def dataType: DataType = child2.dataType

  // Expected input data type.
  override def inputTypes: Seq[AbstractDataType] = Seq(AnyDataType, AnyDataType)

  override def checkInputDataTypes(): TypeCheckResult =
    TypeUtils.checkForOrderingExpr(child1.dataType, "function max")

  private lazy val max = AttributeReference("max", child1.dataType)()
  private lazy val data = AttributeReference("data", child2.dataType)()

  override lazy val aggBufferAttributes: Seq[AttributeReference] = max :: data :: Nil

  override lazy val initialValues: Seq[Expression] = Seq(
    Literal.create(null, child1.dataType),
    Literal.create(null, child2.dataType)
  )

  override lazy val updateExpressions: Seq[Expression] =
    chooseKeyValue(max, data, child1, child2)

  override lazy val mergeExpressions: Seq[Expression] =
    chooseKeyValue(max.left, data.left, max.right, data.right)

  def chooseKeyValue(key1:Expression, value1: Expression, key2:Expression, value2: Expression) = Seq(
    If(IsNull(key1), key2,  If(IsNull(key2), key1,    If(GreaterThan(key1, key2), key1, key2))),
    If(IsNull(key1), value2, If(IsNull(key2), value1, If(GreaterThan(key1, key2), value1, value2)))
  )

  override lazy val evaluateExpression: AttributeReference = data
}

object SparkMoreUDAFs {
  def maxValueByKey(key: Column, value: Column): Column =
      Column(MaxValueByKey(key.expr, value.expr).toAggregateExpression(false))
}
```

And the usage is:

```
sqlContext.table("tbl").groupBy($"id",$"action_type")
          .agg(SparkMoreUDAFs.maxValueByKey($"date", expr("struct(date,*)")).as("s"))
```

I'm not sure it's very elegant but it does the map-side partial aggregation and works for all the column types. Moreover, I think this UDAF is also useful by it self.

Hope it will help someone..

Answer (score 0):

You UDAF (which looks pretty good BTW) works when the keys are sortable. That should also work with `max(struct(key, value))` (let me know if it does not). Maps are currently not orderable, I have done some initial work on it (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15970), but it might need a more holistic approach.

Could you elaborate on the predicate push down? I am curious to see what is happening there.

Comment: Well, of course the keys have to be orderable - we are doing the max on them. The point in my UDAF is to keep all the values (including non-orderables). 
About the predicate push down, let's assume we are doing `select id,action_type,max(struct(date,*)) as s from t1` and then later in the flow we are keeping only some of the fields `select id,action_type,s.col2`. We can expect that the plan optimizer will not even read the raw data of the other columns. But because we have the `max(struct(date,*))` it will read (and shuffle) all the columns

Comment: Ah Ic, the max also requires the values to be orderable.

Comment: The second issue you describe is column pruning for nested data. We are planning to do some work in this area for Spark 2.2, and there is already some work underway https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16043.I am not sure if we are going to prune

Comment: ...across operators.